# Configuring APN through OMA CP

Tags: android, apn, oma

Is it possible to set APN Protocol (specifically this field https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/data/ApnSetting#PROTOCOL_IP)
through OMA Client provisioning (a binary xml with WBXml payload)

So far I have been successful with setting other fields through OMA CP but not Protocol..

Any help is highly appreciated.